# Possible to combine two strings, each with length of PATH_MAX?

Tags: c, string, printf

I want to build a string containing a filename including the full path. My approach on that is as follows:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    char
        fullpath[PATH_MAX],
        workdir[PATH_MAX];
      
    sprintf( workdir, "workdir/" );
    sprintf( fullpath, "%sfilename.dat", workdir);
    printf( "fullpath = %s\n", fullpath );
  
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  
}
```

When compiling, I get the following warning

```
warning: ‘filename.dat’ directive writing 12 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 4096 [-Wformat-overflow=]
sprintf( fullpath, "%sfilename.dat", workdir);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~

note: ‘sprintf’ output between 13 and 4108 bytes into a destination of size 4096
sprintf( fullpath, "%sfilename.dat", workdir);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Do I understand that warning (and the note) correctly, that it might happen that I combine two strings, each with `PATH_MAX` which would then result in problems?

And does that mean I should not combine a string with PATH_MAX with any other string? (At least not in that simplified way I am doing it)

Comment: Use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: Yes, you could run into trouble. If `workdir` contains a very long path, it is possible to overrun the `fullpath` buffer. That is why you should *always* make sure you never write more into a buffer than it can hold.

Comment: @Cheatah ahh, didn't knew about `snprintf`, thanks a lot. I guess the approach would be to ensure with `snprintf` that `PATH_MAX` is not exceeded.

Comment: @Cheatah would something like `snprintf( fullpath, (PATH_MAX-strlen(workdir)), "%sfilename.dat", workdir);` be acceptable or is this still ambiguous?

Comment: You would normally just write `snprintf(fullpath, sizeof fullpath, "%filename.dat", workdir);`

Comment: ... and you should check the return value of `snprintf`. It is the resulting string length. If this is greater than or equal to `sizeof fullpath`, then the resulting string has been truncated to fit into the array.

Comment: @Cheatah Missing `s` in `"%filename.dat"`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting @chux-ReinstateMonica, unfortunately I cannot edit, I don't know why.

Comment: @Cheatah, you could make a new comment and delete old.

Comment: [`PATH_MAX` is not guaranteed to exist](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html)(bolding mine):  "A definition of one of the values **shall be omitted from the `<limits.h>` header** on specific implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the file to which it is applied. The actual value supported for a specific pathname shall be provided by the `pathconf()` function. ... `PATH_MAX` ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Note the quote is not from the C standard, but some implmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprintf( fullpath, "%sfilename.dat", workdir);` gives a warning as `workdir` may be excessively long such that the concatenated size exceeds the size of `fullpath`

A no problem approach to string concatenation: Use `snprintf()` and test its result.

```
int len = snprintf(fullpath, sizeof fullpath, "%sfilename.dat", workdir);
if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof fullpath) {
  Handle_Error();
}
```